# Porting Android application to BlackBerry 10 - image sizes documentation?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I can successfully port my android application to bb10 via eclipse plugin that BlackBerry provides and launch my app in BlackBarry 10 simulator.

Here is my problem. Images in my application are not seems ok. They are scaled and distorted.
I searched but couldn't find a documentation about proper image sizes (except app icon)

Is there a documentation for that? Or how do you use your images?

Thanks

Comment: How did you port android application on BB10 can you give me link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you provide xHDPI images in your application? If not, it's an expected behaviour

Comment: i provided SOME of the images in Xhdpi folder (not all). But result seems different than it appears in Samsung Galaxy S III (i'm speaking for xhdpi images)